# Doc Savage’s fighting style

Tags: history-of, fantasy-genre, authors, martial-arts, pulp

What martial arts did Doc Savage use in the novels? He was portrayed as a martial artist for a pulp character created in 1933. What martial arts could he be using and how many he could have known? Did Lester Dent or Henry W. Ralston ever explain that in an interview?

Comment: i think because this was pre-ww2, japanese martial arts were not very well known in usa. i read all the books years ago, my guess is they would have made doc versed in boxing and wrestling based on vaguest of memories.

Comment: First ten novels; no mention of martial arts, no mention of karate, kung-fu, Ju-jitsu, Taekwondo or any other obvious Eastern fighting style